# given a positive number as a dividend, find out a subset from a given array, so that can get the minimum remainder

Tags: algorithm, numbers

Here are some examples:

given number: 31
given array: [4, 5, 6, 7]
then the result subset will be [4] or [5] as 31 = 4 * 4 + 3 * 5, the remainder is 0,

but if given number: 31
given array: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
then the result subset will be [7, 8] as 31 = 3 * 8 + 1 * 7, the remainder is 0, which is the minimum one.

or if given number: 67
given array: [4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12]
then the result subset will be [4, 9] as 67 = 7 * 9 + 1 * 4, the remainder is 0, which is the minimum one.

So what I want to ask is that if there is an algorithm to find out such subset from a given array, so that one can get the minimum remainder...

Comment: What language are you using? Tag the question appropriately. Where is your code? Add your code to the question (with correct [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). What is not working with your current code? Please [edit] your question with this information.

Comment: Note that 31 = 4*4 + 3*5, so the solution to the first example should be `[4,5]`. In fact the answer to all the examples can be `[4,5]` since 67 = 13*4 + 3*5. For more info, read about [linear Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations).

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for correct the cases and provide the knowledge link, just updated question description.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this task as variant of coin change problem (having sum and some coin nominals, choose the smallest number of coin to compose the sum).

I might be solved with dynamic programming:

Make array `A` of size sum, fill `A[0]` with `0`, other entries with extreme large value.

For every coin `C` walk through array.

Intermediate sum `i` might be composed using coin `C` and sum `i-C`, so check
whether adding `C` to `A[i-C]` will diminish number of coin nominals used for `A[i]` and replace `A[i]` in positive case.

After all `A[sum]` will contain the smallest number of nominals. If it contain initial large value, scan lesser entries (`A[sum-1]` and so on).

Comment: This can fail, e.g. coins 5 and 7, target 42. Now at 35 you might only save the value for the 5 coins and at 42 you think you'll need seven 5 coins and a 7 coin, so at 42 you end up using 5 and 7 coins when it could have been done just using 7 coins.

Comment: OK, I see...  So for "diminish number of coin nominals" we have to store all the best intermediate variants (both 5*7 and 7*5 for your example). Perhaps wasteful...